# P2P not working on Saucy

Tags: deluge, p2p

I have installed two versions of Ubuntu at the same machine. On 12.04 LTS I have torrents working with Deluge and on Saucy it doesn't. It simply doesnt download anything. I unninstaled the firewalls after trying to disable it without sucess. Any help would be great

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only problem I have encountered with P2P was that I forgot to mount the partition of the hard disk on which the data is downloaded. And when I do that I get errors that it can't find the files.

If this is your problem then to mount any partition simply just "open it" from the launcher or from "files". Just open the partition.

Comment: No, I choose download paste to save the temporary files. I think if there is something blocking the p2p communication

Comment: ...I don't understand what you mean by "download paste" but did you try using other programs than deluge? like transmission for example, it comes preinstalled with ubuntu. or vuze?

Comment: I have a folder called downloads at home folder. In portuguese, folder is "pasta" and it was my mistake to write paste. Sorry for that. I unninstaled transmission, but now, as you told me, i tried it and it is working very well. I dint change nothing. Deluge is still not working but i will leave it by side. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Great! you're welcome :D now I know a new word in Portuguese XD ... about Deluge, if you care about it much you can try to reinstalling it and it might work :)

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove deluge-console` ... this removes deluge with its dependencies. Then  `sudo apt-get install deluge` to install it again. also do `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` after installing it (if you will).

Answer (score 0):

I installed Transmission and my problem was solved until I rebooted the system, when it stopped downloading the torrents. I discovered that my problem was with iptables firewall and I followed what was described on this site, wich is in portuguese, http://wiki.ubuntu-br.org/Iptables. Doing that, my problem was really solved and the speed is up to 200 kb/s. Now I'm afraid I opened all the ports to do that and I don't know if someone could hack my system. I will install gufw to prevent this.